# Issue in running loop php

Tags: php, loops, curl

I have written a code to do curl from text area from multiple url to store response data from URL. The problem is the programming is only repeatedly storing the first data only again and again in database. Kindly help me resolve this issue.

This is the code that is having the problem:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $count=0;
    $url_text=$_POST['content'];
    $urls=explode(",",$url_text);
    if(count($urls)>20)
    {
        echo "Url Should not exceed 20";           
    }
    else
    {

        for($j=0;$j<count($urls);$j++)
        {

            if($urls[$j]!='')
            {

                $url=$urls[$j];
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '180');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
                $cUrlResponse = curl_exec($ch);
                $httpResponseArr = curl_getinfo($ch);
                curl_close($ch);

                $new=explode("<td>",$cUrlResponse);
                for($i=1;$i<count($new);$i++)
                {

                    $new_input=explode("</td>",$new[$i]);
                    $content_input=explode(":",$new_input[0]);
                    $content[]=trim($content_input[1]);

                }
                $stmt4 = $db->prepare("insert into example (data1,data2,data3) values ('$content[0]','$content[1]','$content[2]')");
                $stmt4->execute();
                $count++;

            }
            echo $count." Rows Inserted Successfully....";

        }

    }

}
?>
<form method="post" method="">

    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: On a side note, you should consider properly indenting your code. I don't know how you can even read it like that.

Answer (score 1):

You append items to your `$content` array, but you don't ever reset that array, so the first three values remain the same, which you then insert into you db.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your `content` array. The way you have it set up, data is just stacking into it and not overwriting.

Add `$content = array();` just before your `$new` variable.

As a side note, indentation will go a **LONG** way:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $count=0;
    $url_text=$_POST['content'];
    $urls=explode(",",$url_text);
    if(count($urls)>20){
        echo "Url Should not exceed 20";           
    }else{
        for($j=0;$j<count($urls);$j++){
            if($urls[$j]!=''){
                $url=$urls[$j];
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '180');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
                $cUrlResponse = curl_exec($ch);
                $httpResponseArr = curl_getinfo($ch);
                curl_close($ch);

                $content = array();
                $new=explode("<td>",$cUrlResponse);
                for($i=1;$i<count($new);$i++){
                    $new_input=explode("</td>",$new[$i]);
                    $content_input=explode(":",$new_input[0]);
                    $content[]=trim($content_input[1]);
                }
                $stmt4 = $db->prepare("insert into example (data1,data2,data3) values ('$content[0]','$content[1]','$content[2]')");
                $stmt4->execute();
                $count++;
            }
            echo $count." Rows Inserted Successfully....";
        }
    }
}?>
<form method="post" method="">
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: all data are stored blank. earlier it atleast ran and got one data and stored it multiple times.